# Can't see what "subscript out of range"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro in VBA in Excel to copy the contents of one worksheet to another (eventually will be upgraded to copying contents from one workbook to another but need to prove the concept first) but I keep encountering Run-time error '9': "Subscript out of range".  The thing is, I can't see what part of the highlighted line could possibly ever be out of range.

I am using a workbook called "MetaTesting" that has 3 worksheets, and the following bit of code starts at A1 and only ever increments upwards. I have previously been able to refer to these two worksheets to be able to copy across a single row, so I know the problem isn't there. It is the fourth line of text that is being highlighted by the debugger (the line starting "Do While Trim(Application...").

Note: edited to take into account file name extension (as suggested in comments).  Same error still being thrown, but now it's being thrown on line 11 (under the first comment)

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
i = 1

Do While Trim(Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Cells(i, 1).Value) <> ""
    j = 1
    Do While Trim(Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Cells(1, j).Value) <> ""

        'Copy cell data from one sheet to the other
        Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, j).Value = Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlms").Worksheets(3).Cells(i, j).Value

        j = j + 1
    Loop

    'Copy formatting of previous row and paste it on current row. Starts at row 3, copying formatting from row 2
    If i > 2 Then
        k = i - 1
        Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Cells(k, j).Copy
        Application.Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, j)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use `Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long`?

Comment: Use `Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm")` or `Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsb")` as the case may be; whatever is reported by `?thisworkbook.Name` in the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G). (btw, none of those `Application` calls seem necessary)

Comment: @Jeeped it shouldn't need to be declared as a Long as the section I'm testing with is only about 10 by 10.  However, adding the .xlsm to the end of the workbook name did migrate the error to line 11 (under the first comment).  Same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without all the loops, just copy the whole worksheet - the Copy function will handle skipping empty areas for you.

```
Workbooks("MetaTesting").Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
Workbooks("MetaTesting").Worksheets(2).Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

To copy only a block of cells:

```
Workbooks("MetaTesting").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:M100").Copy
Workbooks("MetaTesting").Worksheets(2).Range("F12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  ' this is the top-left corner of the paste, it'll fill in the rest
```

Comment: Since the problem seems to originating before any copying commences, I believe the actual issue is either in the `Workbooks("MetaTesting")` or variable assignment. While you make a valid point, I don't think it addresses the issue at hand.

Comment: Would this copying method work if the block of cells to be copied is of an unknown length?

Comment: This does work, and it makes my life a lot easier! Just wondering, how would I refer to a whole column except for the first row?

Comment: @Imamadmad - When you change the conditions of your question to the point where a previously right answer becomes wrong, it is considered good [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ettiquette to accept the answer provided and move on to another question.

Comment: @Jeeped The conditions of the question didn't change.  I was receiving an error when I was doing it my way and asked for help, and somebody provided a much simpler way to solve the problem which avoided the error.  You did help by suggesting to put the extension on the end of the question in one of your comments, but it didn't solve the whole problem and I can only accept 1 answer.  I will however upvote all three answers as they all played a part in helping solve the problem.

Comment: Hehe, I just managed to make my first upvotes! Man I've been wanting to be able to do that for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The issue on line 11 is probably due to the ("MetaTesting.xlms").  Looks like a little mistake on the file extentions; should be .xlsm like it is in the first half of the equation.

Comment: Ah, this does solve one of my problems, but I am marking the other answer because it solves more of them.  Thanks for the help!  It's always those small things that are missed!

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that it is determined that the workbook extension was required, let's cut your code down to what is necessary.

```
with Workbooks("MetaTesting.xlsm")
    .Worksheets(3).Cells.Copy Destination:=.Worksheets(1).Cells
    .Worksheets(1).Cells = .Worksheets(1).Cells.Value
end with
```